# Change the alertBody of a repeating local notification

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

Is it possible to have a repeating local notification with a different alertBody each time? If not, how could I implement such functionality?

**CODE (EDIT)**

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60)
// randomItem is an extension in the code.
notification.alertBody = self.athkar.randomItem()
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Minute

UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Comment: No, once a notification is scheduled you can't change it. You need to schedule multiple notifications.

Comment: @Paulw11 Oh, alright thank you! I'll look into that